# Noisy points from point cloud causes Moveit! to fail

Tags: ros, moveit, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As shown in the screenshot below, some of the points (green) from the Kinect2 camera point cloud (`kinect2/sd/points`) are really close to the robot, due to sensor noise.

[image: image description]

These points overlap with the gripper, and causes Moveit! to keep output the following message:

```
Motion plan was found but it seems to be too costly and looking around did not help.
```

and the plan was in state ABORTED.

When I turn off the OctoMap layer for Moveit!, the arm can execute the motion plan smoothly.

How can I either remove these noisy points or tell Moveit! to not worry about these points?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395059/noisy-points-from-point-cloud-causes-moveit!-to-fail/) by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2022-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind. It is actually straightforward to filter out those points, using the PassThrough filter and the StatisticalOutlierRemoval filter from [pcl_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/filters#Common_ROS_parameters). Pasting my launch file below for a reference in case someone runs into the same issue.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pcl_manager" args="manager" output="screen" />

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
        name="pass_through_z"
        args="load pcl/PassThrough pcl_manager">
    <param name="filter_field_name" value="z" />
    <param name="filter_limit_min" value="0.25" />
    <param name="filter_limit_max" value="3.0" />
    <param name="filter_limit_negative" value="False" />
    <remap from="~input" to="/kinect2/sd/points"/>
    <remap from="~output" to="/kinect2/sd/filtered_passthrough_z"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
        name="statistical_filter"
        args="load pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl_manager">
    <param name="mean_k" value="100" />
    <param name="stddev" value="0.1" />
    <remap from="~input" to="/kinect2/sd/filtered_passthrough_z"/>
    <remap from="~output" to="/kinect2/sd/filtered_points"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

See screenshot below for the point cloud after filtering.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) with karma: 178 on 2022-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1